# Multiple independent lines in the same 3D Axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, mplot3d

I would like to draw multiple independent lines in a 3D plot in Python. It looks like: [image].

I am new at Python. Would you help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to 3D plot function of 2 variables in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765184/how-to-3d-plot-function-of-2-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You have to work with matplotlib library  ([mplot3d](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) package).

Here is a little example of 3dr plot with lines:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make 3d axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# test data
x = np.arange(-1., 1., .1)
y = np.arange(-1., 1., .1)
z1 = x + y
z2 = x * x
z3 = -y * y

# plot test data
ax.plot(x, y, z1)
ax.plot(x, y, z2)
ax.plot(x, y, z3)

# make labels
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much